# Inclusion–exclusion principle, password combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

Co-workers are required to create 6-character long passwords. The letters must be from lowercase letters or digits. Each password must start with a lowercase letter and end with a digit and contain at most 2 digits. How many valid passwords are there?

Is my answer correct? What I'm doing wrong if not?
$$26 \cdot 36^3 \cdot 10 - 36^2 + 26^2$$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: This can't be right as the corrections only consider two characters each.  The first part only considers five characters.  Maybe you intended some parentheses somewhere.  If so, please supply them.  Some words on the logic of your expression also makes it much easier to understand.

Comment: It would be easier to consider cases, depending on whether a password contains one or two digits.

Answer (score 2):

Just consider two cases

*Case 1, only one digit at end* : $\;26\cdot36^4\cdot10$

*Case 2, an extra digit somewhere in the middle:*$\;26\cdot36^3\cdot\binom41\cdot10\cdot10$

Add up

Comment: Ah ok, now much more clear for me. You mean adding up both case1 and case2 ?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I mean